# How/why is “ *[attribute^="string" ” a valid querySelector? (JS bug?)

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, css-selectors

So, this might be a bug... I mistyped a CSS path to check for elements that had been processed to have a particular onclick function beginning `"ajaxLoad("`

```
document.querySelectorAll( 'a[onclick^="ajaxLoad("' )
```

As you can see, I forgot to close the attribute accessor, with `]`, like so :

```
document.querySelectorAll( 'a[onclick^="ajaxLoad(]"' )
```

Weirdly, it worked!

> **Edit** - no I didn't, I actually ran the correct CSS selector:
>
> ```
> document.querySelectorAll( 'a[onclick^="ajaxLoad("]' )
> ```
>
> ... but as mentioned in the comments apparently this further typo also works!

This is obviously invalid. I spotted it when I came to add another type of link, of class `tc-link`, and was wondering if I could just chain it like in CSS stylesheets as :

```
document.querySelectorAll( 'a[onclick^="ajaxLoad(", a.tc-link' )
```

The answer is that you can by closing that bracket, but *not* when this typo is left in.

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': 'a[onclick^="ajaxLoad(", a tc-link' is not a valid selector.

It works on `^=`, `$=`, and `*=`, and from what I can see doesn't happen in Firefox or Opera (and I don't have any other browsers to test in).

I was thinking this was a language quirk at first but revised question: can anyone work out which level (DOM? V8? Er.. webkit? I don't know the ins and outs that well) of Javascript/browser code this relates to, and where it can get reported/fixed?

Comment: IE appears to behave the same as Chrome. It's not every day you have two of the buggiest browsers screw up on the exact same thing. Note that your way of closing with `]` is incorrect as you have the `]` before the `"` and not after, but strangely it works too. Also worth adding is that it fails correctly in CSS, in all browsers.

Comment: Haha, I actually went back and added that example in to illustrate - first time round in my console I did run it like that, but how strange they both work!

Comment: The selector parser will maintain the set of permissible tokens at every parse position. After the closing double quote, that would be `]` and nothing else. So your chained selector fails, since the parser cannot reliably guess what you wanted to express. Otoh, if the end of the string to be parsed has been reached, error recovery will be much easier in general and specifically in the depicted situation, since what is missing is but syntactic sugar (assuming that you intended to let your selector end there).

Comment: @collapsar: The problem is that the error correction you speak of is not supposed to happen. The given selector is invalid, period, and should throw a SYNTAX_ERR.

Comment: @BoltClock Sure you are right wrt the specs. Otoh, this appears to be a deliberate decision (in particular given the tolerated token swap you mention).

Comment: @collapsar: Looks like my original comment wasn't clear - it does not appear to be treated as a token swap, just an extra `]` in the attribute value. It might not match the right elements, but I meant to say it won't cause a SYNTAX_ERR for the same reason not having it at all doesn't.

Comment: This bug is soo weird! Using `a[onclick=""` on this page works. WTH? Even `a[onclick="][onclick` works!!! (notice the missing `"]` at the end) For short, `a[onclick="` works too!

Comment: @BoltClock Ok, so I had misunderstood you indeed.

Comment: IE appears to have had this problem since [at least version 9](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9618), though at that point I wouldn't be surprised if IE8 (its first `querySelectorAll()` implementation) had the same problem.

Comment: I don't know why this is even a question.  If you're asking "why does this work?", then all answers would be purely speculative:  only the browser vendors in question can answer that.  You already have a working test case, so submit the bug report already.

Comment: @cimmanon It's a question because, as I wrote in the question, I'm asking why does it work, i.e. at what level of code is this bug at. As I asked clearly in the question, "can anyone work out which level (DOM? V8? Er.. webkit?)". I'm not a CS student and not a web dev, hence asking here. There's no single "Javascript" which this could be submitted as a report on, like I might for e.g. Python. It seemed to be Chrome-specific at first but apparently also affects IE. That issue is not speculative, and amounts to testing in browsers which I don't have, such as IE. That's why I asked the question.

Comment: @Louis You don't need any of that to file a bug report.  If you don't know what's expected when filing a bug report, I suggest you take the time to read other submissions that were well received.

Comment: Ok I will do when I get home in the next couple of hours - would anyone want to volunteer for submitting it to IE bug tracker... Else I'll have to do it without having tried in that browser (I'm on Linux) cc @BoltClock. Will post an answer with submission links unless someone has done so already - thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is primarely opinion-based and is nowhere close to a definitive answer.

Browsers are EXTREMELY complex. Done! Nothing is predictable on them.

First, let's analyze a list of faulty selectors:

- `a[onclick^="ajaxLoad("` (missing `]`)
- `a[onclick^="ajaxLoad(]"` (missing `]`)
- `a[onclick=""` (missing `]`)
- `a[onclick="][onclick` (missing `"]` or missing `"` and `]` based on what you need)
- `a[onclick=""][onclick` (missing `]`)
- `a[onclick="` (missing `"]`)
- `a[onclick` (missing `]`)
- `a:not([onclick]` (missing `)`)
- `a:not([onclick` (missing `])`)
- `a:not([onclick="` (missing `"])`)
- `a:nth-child(5):not([onclick="` (missing `"])`)
- `a:-webkit-any(:not([onclick="` (missing `"]))`)

So far, this is the list found. I can confirm that these work on Google Chrome 41.0.2272.89m on Windows 7.

Notice the pattern? It's simple: Chrome still can use there selectors to match the elements by filling with basic missing characters, but **only** at the end!
What is missing is so predictable it doesn't require too much effort to fix.
But not every selector can/will be 'fixed' (E.g.: `a,`, can be fixed by adding `*`).

This may be a bug or a feature (aka, an embarrassing bug submitted as a feature) to soften the eagerness of the CSS engine. This also affects jQuery since jQuery only uses [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) if `document.querySelectorAll()` doesn't exist or throws an exception.

With some time we can find many more.

**Disclaimer:**

This behaviour *shouldn't* be relied upon and *may* change in the future.
This is all based on **invalid** selectors and invalid syntax (like some IE CSS Hacks for older versions). **ALL** the working selectors on the list above are against the spec.

The 'unfixed' selector given as an example (`a,`) **works** in jQuery, but that is unrelated to this question. Essentially, jQuery will execute it as `a`.

Answer (score 6):

The reason why most browsers accept the missing closing bracket is that they're all following the same algorithm from [CSS specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-syntax/#rule-defs). There is a discussion about this on the Chromium bugtracker; here's the relevant excerpt from the [comment](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=460399#c6) that closed the bug as WontFix:

> When you parse the string 'a[b=c' (from the example link), the CSS parser turns that into:
>
> ```
> IDENT(A)
> SIMPLE [ BLOCK:
>     IDENT(B)
>     DELIM(=)
>     IDENT(C)
> ```
>
> The fact that the square-bracket block was unclosed is lost.  You can think of this as the parser "auto-closing all unclosed blocks".  If you're using a spec-compliant parser, it is literally impossible to detect an unclosed block unless you do a separate ad hoc parsing on your own just for that purpose.

(I know I'm gravedigging an old question here, but since this still [comes up](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/5nbmqi/on_handling_invalid_selector_strings/) from time to time, the link and explanation may be useful.)

Comment: Do you know then why they don't accept it as part of the CSS rules?