# Using CSS :not selector with jquery

Tags: jquery, ios, css

I have the following code to implement smooth scrolling to internal anchor links, the code works on PC's and Android but not with Apple devices;

```
// The function used for smooth scrolling internal links
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var topbanner=$("#top-banner").css("height");
  var navbar=$(".navbar").css("height");
  var brand=$(".brand").css("height");
  var gap =$(".page-style").css("margin-top");

  topbanner = (isNaN(topbanner = parseInt(topbanner, 10)) ? 0 : topbanner),
  navbar = (isNaN(navbar = parseInt(navbar, 10)) ? 0 : navbar),
  brand = (isNaN(brand = parseInt(brand, 10)) ? 0 : brand),
  gap = (isNaN(gap = parseInt(gap, 10)) ? 0 : gap),

  topmargin=topbanner+navbar+brand+gap;


   $('a[href*="#"]:not([href*="tab"]').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

      var target = $(this.hash);

      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');

      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top-topmargin
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

The issue lies with the line;

```
$('a[href*="#"]:not([href*="tab"]').click(function() {
```

Where I would like it to work on clicking an anchor unless the anchors starts with #tab but this does not seem to work on Apple devices and throws up an error that it is an unrecognized statement. Is there a way to rectify the code so that it works.

Comment: You have a typo. `a[href*="#"]:not([href*="tab"]` is missing a `)` at the end. Your code could not possibly work anywhere.

Comment: It does work on FF, IE and Android.for me.

Comment: You're right, I just remembered commenting on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29120822/how-why-is-attribute-string-a-valid-queryselector-js-bug), which lists a number of querySelectorAll selectors that seem to work in certain browsers despite being invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently using the `*=` selector which represents "contains". If you wanted to narrow this down, you could use the [`^=` starts with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and only target `<a>` tags that do not start with `#tab` :

```
 // Target <a> tags that start with '#' but not '#tab'
 $('a[href^="#"]:not(a[href^="#tab"])').click(function(){
       // Your code here
 });
```

or if you wanted to only ignore those that start with `#tab`, you could include all links and just add that into the `:not()` statement :

```
// Target all <a> tags except those that start with '#tab'
$('a:not(a[href^="#tab"])').click(function(){
       // Your code here
});
```

**Example**

You can [see a working example of this here](http://jsbin.com/piqorem/1/edit?html,console,output) and demonstrated below :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the ":not(...)" part form the selector and check for the href inside the click function. If it starts with #tab you could return without doing anything.

Of course this fires more click events than necessary.

EDIT: By the way there is a missing bracket in your selector: the not() is never closed. Maybe that solves the problem!??